# How do I write a JS function in GTM that captures product name from enhanced ecommerce code?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am not a developer or even too familiar with coding protocol/structure. However, I need to write a javascript function that returns product name when a product is sold by capturing it from the Google Analytics enhanced ecommerce code. Here is the example code:

```
{
   event: 'purchase',
   ecommerce: {
      purchase: {
         actionField: {
            id: '000000',
            affiliation: 'fictional source',
            revenue: '25.99',
            tax: '5.00',
            shipping: '0',
            coupon: 'NC',
         },
         products: [{
            name: 'fictional product',
            id: '33',
            price: '9.99',
            brand: 'fictional brand',
            category: 'fictional category',
            quantity: 1
         }]
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see the 'name' is nested under 'products' and I'm not sure if it's also considered nested under 'ecommerce' and/or 'purchase'.

My goal in this example would be to create a variable in GTM that is based on custom javascript that returns the product name when this product is sold and is undefined whenever there is no purchase. So here, I would want the variable to capture 'fictional product'.

I've tried doing this in many ways without luck but I'm sure it's pretty simple for someone experienced. Can anyone assist?

Comment: In your code example (which is syntactically incorrect but i assume just example purpose..) the path to product name is `ecommerce.products[0].name`  you can create a GTM Variable of **Data Layer Variable** type and use that as the **Data Layer Variable Name**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard enhanced ecommerce dataLayer structure, then this can be done by defining a Data Layer Variable in GTM with the following value:

```
ecommerce.purchase.products.0.name
```

using the dot notation.

Comment: I've tried using this approach, based on comments in Simo Ahava's blog. But when I debug in preview mode, the value for this is undefined. I do not end up seeing a product name. Do you know of anything that might prevent this approach from working?

Comment: You *should* use it at the same time that your `'event': 'purchase'` happens, otherwise you will not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
   event: 'purchase',
   ecommerce: {
      purchase: {
         actionField: {
            id: '000000',
            affiliation: 'fictional source',
            revenue: '25.99',
            tax: '5.00',
            shipping: '0',
            coupon: 'NC',
         },
         products: [{
            name: 'fictional product',
            id: '33',
            price: '9.99',
            brand: 'fictional brand',
            category: 'fictional category',
            quantity: 1
         }]
      }
   }
};


let productName = data["ecommerce"]["purchase"]["products"][0]["name"];

console.log(productName)
```